# Cross server AJAX Request - Works in all browsers but IE

Tags: php, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Having some problems getting my cross server request to work in IE. Is it possible at all? I've read up on Cross Server Requests, and it seems it depends completely on the browser. If I run the function below in any other browser bar IE, it returns the 'success' function, IE just returns the 'error' function.

My question is, is it possible to get this to return 'success' in IE at all?

I've stripped down my JS code to the following:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.getJSON($this.attr('action'))
.error(function() {

    console.log('ERROR');

}).success(function() {

    console.log('success');

});
```

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: I think this is a security setting in IE.  https://jobs.missouri.edu/howtos/DisableIE8XSS.pdf

Comment: do you see any errors in the developer tools i guess the firebug equivalent in IE

Comment: I think generally IE doesn't allow cross site server requests.

Comment: @3nigma - Chrome and Firefox do..

Comment: @3nigma - I've run this - http://pastebin.com/sLMDYT6t

Comment: @christian.thomas no i wanted to ask in IE do you see any errors when you make the ajax request ?

Comment: Nope, no errors - Just http://pastebin.com/96dM0ZE9 if i console log what's returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do cross domain AJAX requests you need to make a JSONP request which you can do by appending 'callback=?' to your url.

Comment: jquery automagically does this when it detects that the request is cross-domain and you are using the json datatype.

Comment: I've tried adding callback=? - But all it does it make it error in all browsers. Does my PHP Script need to return anything particular?

Comment: yes, it needs to be `echo $_GET["callback"]."(".json_encode($array).")"`

Answer (score 0):

log the error message like

```
$.getJSON($this.attr('action'))
.error(function(jxhr) {

    console.log(jxhr.status+" --- "+jxhr.responseText);

}).success(function(data) {

    console.log('success');

});
```

what does this `console.log(jxhr.status+" --- "+jxhr.responseText);` line says in IE also try specifying the `contentType` like

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false,
  crossDomain: true, 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
 });
```

hope this will help

Comment: That console.log just returns - LOG: 0 --- undefined

Comment: try specifying the `contentType` in `ajaxSetup`

Comment: Mmmm.. I tried I think, I just need to put ajaxSetup before the getJSON function right? If so, I've done that but it still returns the same.. I've also got header('Content-type: application/json'); at the top of my php file being called

Comment: try adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in the php file

Comment: Got that at the top too, it seems the answer above is coming together though. I'm at least getting the 'success' function! Thanks for your help

Comment: so adding the `header` solved the problem or specifying the `contentType` in the `ajaxSetup`?